# Stored Procedures in MS-SQL Server 2005 and Oracle

Tags: sql-server-2005, oracle, stored-procedures

How to translate MS-SQL Server 2005 stored procedures into Oracle stored procedures?
A chart contrasting corresponding features from each environment with each other - would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

http://vyaskn.tripod.com/oracle_sql_server_differences_equivalents.htm is a good resource